# Windows 8 turns screens off on lock

Tags: windows-8.1

When I lock Windows 8.1 (I have 3 displays) all of them will turn black. I want to keep my screens open and I've also set this in the **Energy Manager** to 5 hours before turning screens to sleep.

However, they still go to black after a few seconds after I lock my PC. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a setting that can be added for this. See http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8267-power-options-add-console-lock-display-off-timeout.html to find out how to add a key to your registry, so that you can change the time it takes for your computer to go to sleep when you lock your computer.
(and yes it is VERY annoying feature.. I have my computer start up in the morning, auto logon and then auto lock the screens, so that my programs can start.. but then it goes to sleep after 1 minute..)

Comment: Thanks for adding this as answer. I've found indeed the same solution but forgot to post about it. The credits are yours now.

Answer (score 0):

That has to be a Power Management setting, Either relating to Hard Drives or Hibernation or Sleep or Monitor Setting times, obviously,

Now, you said that you already check it,  i would suggest looking at it again and in a lot more detail, it's probably one of those things where you change it in one place, but it needs to be changed in another as well,

Like in Windows 7 When you set the PC to Never Turn off , but it still does because of the hard drive settings to shut off after 10mins or something like that

Now.. a little off topic, but since your talking about this

How about , when you do get it to do what you want, it may interest you to change the default background while in Lock Mode,

check this out..  Your Welcome

(http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5382-log-screen-change.html?ltr=L)